# How to get pinch scaling data for x and y axis

Tags: ios, swift

I've seen the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and how it can be used for a single scale variable, but is there a way to get individual scales for the x and y axes?

Answer (score -1):

There is no simple way to do that with `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. Maybe by subclassing `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` or directly `UIGestureRecognizer` you could do it, but this is going to be hard.

The easiest way is to add a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`. Then knowing the rotation and scale you can compute the scale for each axis by doing a projection.